# Apache Spark :org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.drop(String... colNames) method for Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables, with two common columns.
I am doing join using those columns.
Now I want to drop common columns from one of the table.
I checked API and found that here are many overloaded methods in Spark.

One of them is : `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.drop(String... colNames)`

However my question is how to specify table name from which we want to drop a column. Is there any way?

I searched and found that there is some concept of aliases but I am not sure how to apply same for this method.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that there are few ways :

1) To rename columns before joining.

2) dropping one column at a type

```
ex. `df1.drop(df2.col("ACCT_NBR"));`
```

by above expression we get DF as return type and we can again call drop function on same for number of times.

This resolves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Dataframe/Dataset of the table and then use `.drop()`

```
Dataset<Row> sa = spark.read().option("multiLine", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json("file-path");
sa.drop("col-name");
```